# WebService with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am working on my first jQuery and also ASP.Net webservice but it won't run and hoping someone can show me the errors of my ways please?

I have a jsFiddle set up: http://jsfiddle.net/3hufY/1/ with the basic HTML and jQuery on 1.10.1

Code for asmx file below (sorry its in VB)

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the    following line.
'<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
'<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
'<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
'<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class myService
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function FullName(ByRef First As String, ByRef Last As String) As String
    Return "Your name is " & First & " " & Last
End Function

End Class
```

In the fiddle its showing full URL, on local I am only showing local URL, just in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Can you tell us what your exact problem is?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3hufY/4/

Comment: I am not getting a response, instead it is coming back with error

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the `ScriptService` part of your script, which is commented out now.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To invoke a Web service method from ECMAScript (JavaScript), you must apply the ScriptServiceAttribute attribute to the related Web service class

I do suggest when you are starting a new project to look into WCF or Web API since ASMX webservices are end-of-life. Those frameworks are very easy to use, especially for these scenarios.

Comment: @MarkCooney: It will not work unless you use SOAP, which is much harder to read then JSON. You should really use another platform. See [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Comment: I dont seem to have WebAPI as an option to me. I am using VS2010 on a server 2008 OS

Comment: @MarkCooney: See this [post](http://robertbigec.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/developing-mvc-4-web-api-with-visual-studio-2010/). It should also work on Server 2008.

Comment: As always tutorials are not very VB friendly so am now even more confused than I was this morning. I am only a hobbiest so learning languages is not really something I have time for. Microsoft either need to support VB.Net or get rid. Thanks for help anyway @patrick_hofman

Answer (score 0):

Do the following change on your webservice

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function FullName(ByRef First As String, ByRef Last As String) As String
    Return "Your name is " & First & " " & Last
End Function
```

Check whether you placed  or 
If you are not having ScriptManager , Importing Script.Service will show error